# Spring @Scheduled task in multiple timezones

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a client that operates across the US (in all time zones). I need to run a task at 2AM in each time zone. This task needs time zone as input to fetch records only related that zone.

@Scheduled annotation has `timezone` value, that works of one timezone at a time.

I do not want to duplicate the code by having 4 separate tasks for each zone.

Comment: can you try using repeatable annotations in java 8, hit this link for docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html

Answer (score 3):

Use zone property with annotation @Scheduled, (version 4.0 addition)
See Example below

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 19 * * FRI", zone = "CET")
```

Comment: Using this, I can run a task at 2AM in CET. But I want to run at 2AM in all timezones. Like 2AM EST, 2AM CST, 2AM MST and 2AM PST.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class TestBean implements SmartInitializingSingleton {

  @Inject
  TaskScheduler scheduler;

  @Bean
  public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler te = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    te.setPoolSize(4);
    return te;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {

    Arrays.stream(new String[] {"PST", "MST", "CST", "EST"})
        .forEach(zone -> {
          scheduler.schedule(() -> {
            log.info("Zone trigged: {}", zone);
          }, new CronTrigger("0 0 2 * * *", TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone)));
        });
  }
}
```

You may want to separate out the different concerns of creating the scheduler bean and the task execution. Also, take care to choose a suitable scheduler that has the parallelism you need in the event that a job runs over into the trigger time of the next job.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this approach ?
As per java 8 [repeatable annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html) docs it should work,@Repeatable is already included in @Scheduled, so no need to declare @scheduled again with @Repeatable annotation

> org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled
>
> @Repeatable(value=Schedules.class)
>    @Target(value={ANNOTATION_TYPE,
>   METHOD}) 
>   @Retention(value=RUNTIME) @Documented

```
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 1,13 * * ?", zone = "CST")
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 1,15 * * ?", zone = "SGT")
    public void doScheduledWork() {
        //complete scheduled work
    }
.
.
.
```

related docs/links : [java-8 repeatable custom annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951519/java-8-repeatable-custom-annotations)
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-8-type-annotations-and-repeating-annotations

Answer (score 0):

a stupid but work solution would be put the content of the logic in another function
and call the schedule in 2 different function with different schedule setting

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 19 * * FRI", zone = "CET") 
public void scheduleCetTask() {
    // code to get parameters
    commonTask(parameters);
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 19 * * FRI", zone = "ABC") 
public void scheduleAbcTask() {
    // code to get parameters
    commonTask(parameters);
}

public void commonTask(parameters) {
}
```